# How to display default values in bound form?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.Net form bound to a datatable.

Let's assume the following datatable:

```
    Dim DataTable As New DataTable
    DataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID"))
    DataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("NAME"))
    DataTable.Columns("ID").AllowDBNull = False
    DataTable.Columns("NAME").AllowDBNull = False
```

The form has two textboxes bound to the datatable :

```
    Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("text", DataTable, "ID")
    Me.TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("text", DataTable, "NAME")
```

Now I want to add a new row to the datatable with a default value in the ID. I have two ways to do it.

### 1st method

```
    Me.DataTable.Rows.Add()
```

This method doesn't work. It raises the error : **Column 'ID' does not allow nulls.**

### 2nd method

```
    Dim NewRow As DataRow
    NewRow = DataTable.NewRow

    'Add ID default value
    NewRow.Item("ID") = 1
    .
    .
    .
    'Once the user filled the field Name
    NewRow.Item("NAME") = TextBox2.text
    DataTable.Rows.add(NewRow)
```

The problem with this second method is that, the default value affected doesn't appear in the ID text box which is quite normal since this row has not yet been added the Datatable. And I can not neither add it to the datatable if the Column "NAME" has not yet been filled.

Does it mean that I can never have the default value displayed in the form ?

Does anyone have an idea on how to display default values on the form with respect to AllowDBNull property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the DefaultValue property of the DataColumn:

```
DataTable.Columns("ID").DefaultValue = 0
DataTable.Columns("NAME").DefaultValue = "Test"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about if the Column NAME doesn't have a default value and should be filled by the user ?

Comment: @ThomasCarlton The confusing part of your post is that you are binding the TextBox2 property to a data table, which will only bind to the first row since you aren't using something that has a currency manager, like a BindingSource, etc.  You can always make the DefaultValue equal to String.Empty and then use Validation on the TextBox2 control that would require a valid input.